# What is different about tibbles and data.frames after a group_by statement

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sample, tibble

If I take a tibble and try to sample it, it works fine,

```
dft <- tibble(a=rnorm(200),b=seq.int(1,200),c=sample(LETTERS[1:26],200,replace = T))
sample_frac(dft,.5)
# A tibble: 100 x 3
     a     b c    
 <dbl> <int> <chr>
1 -0.233     58 S    
2  0.0529    82 Y    
3  0.371     31 S    
4  0.978    136 Z    
5  0.878    106 S    
6  0.253     46 D    
7 -1.07      16 W    
8 -1.98     193 Y    
9 -0.890     51 H    
10  0.151     75 A    
# ... with 90 more rows
```

but if I group that tibble and then try to sample the grouped tibble it returns an empty tibble.

```
dft <- dft %>% group_by(c) %>% count()              
sample_frac(dft,.5)
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# Groups:   c [0]
# ... with 2 variables: c <chr>, n <int>
```

If I coerce the tibble to a data.frame, the sampling works.
The issue was [reported](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/405) as a bug and closed some time ago, so I am guessing it is not something easily fixed.

What is different about tibbles and data.frames that causes issues like this one?

Comment: There are attributes generated with the `group_by`.  If you convert to `data.frame`, those gets lost

Comment: It looks like there is only one row for each value of `c`. If you use `%>% sample_frac(0.5)` on one row it will return a 0-row tibble. For example: `data.frame(a = 1) %>% sample_frac(.5)` returns a 0-row tibble. I don't think this has anything to do with differences between tibbles and data.frames

Comment: This would work: `dft %>% count(c) %>% sample_frac(.5)`. In addition to @Ryan's comment: note that there is only one observation per group that you try to sample from.

Comment: @Ryan It works if you use `sample_frac(as.data.frame(dft),.5)`

Comment: That’s because when you do `as.data.frame` you're removing the groups.

Comment: @markus I should say, this is only a example. In the code where I ran into this issue, I was trying to plot a representative sample from a dataframe that included some 4 million rows, but was grouping by an index that repeated, much like the column c in the example code(though not periodically).

Comment: @Ryan That's why it has to do with the difference between a tibble and a data.frame, but what I would like to know is _why_ at a structural level this happens.  What is the use for preserving the grouping information? Just so you can call ungroup()?

Comment: That's just what they decided the behavior should be. See https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2963 . It would be more accurate to say this is an (intentional) difference between grouped tibbles and ungrouped tibbles/data.frames, rather than a difference between tibbles and data.frames. If you remove the groups and keep it as a tibble you get the result you expect. `sample_frac` is intended to (and does) work on groups if the tibble is grouped.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the link, that does clarify quite a bit.  But I am curious what you mean when you say sample_frac does work on groups if the tibble is grouped.  Can you give me an example?  If, in the sample code I instead `%>% group_by(c,b,a) %>%        
sample_frac(.5)`, thereby preserving all rows from the initial tibble, I still get an empty tibble as a result. If the intention of sample_frac was to preserve the distribution of the grouped column, it should be able to give something of a representative sample (I have tried it with 26,000 rows to be sure).

Comment: How big are the groups? If the groups are one row each, an empty tibble is what should be returned.

Comment: @Ryan Oh I figured it out. In my last example, it was trying to pull representative samples of the continous variables as well. If I only `group_by(c)` it works as you said. Thanks